# how do i make spinning buttons functional when radnumerictextbox is in readonly mode..?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-radinput

how do i make spinning buttons functional when radnumerictextbox is in readonly mode..?

I am using Telerik's with spinning Buttons...
i need RadNumericTextBox is in Readonly mode but it need to update with spinning buttons...

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="radntxt_TimePickers" AutoPostBack="false" runat="server"
                                MinValue="1" MaxValue="20" ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="radntxt_TimePickers_CreateTimePickers" 
                                NumberFormat-AllowRounding="true" NumberFormat-DecimalDigits="0" NumberFormat-GroupSeparator="" 
                                IncrementSettings-InterceptMouseWheel="true" Width="40px" ShowSpinButtons="true" ReadOnly="true">
                               </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to make it readonly or not along with the spinning buttons.

You could use the code found here to make it readonly:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/input/radtextbox-set-read-only.aspx

Set it to false to make it editable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function setReadOnly()  
{  
    var TextBox1 = $find("<%= RadTextBox1.ClientID %>");  
    TextBox1._textBoxElement.readOnly = true;  
}  
</script>
```

Note that $find is specifically for ASP.NET

Comment: What did you make readonly? In the example I gave, TextBox1._textBoxElement became readonly. In your case, radntxt_TimePickers needs to have its readonly property changed.

Comment: Textbox becoming Readonly... good but, when i cick on spnning buttons for same textbox value needs to be changed....

Comment: So make .readOnly = false when one of those spinning buttons is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I added an OnKeyPress client-side event to the textbox
then added a Javascript function to cancel the event

```js
    <telerik:radnumerictextbox id="RadTextBox1" showspinbuttons="true" runat="server">  
         <ClientEvents OnKeyPress="OnKeyPress" />  
    </telerik:radnumerictextbox>
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function OnKeyPress(sender, eventArgs) 
{ 
   eventArgs.set_cancel(true);    
} 
</script>
```